# List comprehension with tuple assignment

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to ask if something like this is possible in python:

```
a,b = [i,i+1 for i in range(5)]
```

I know this isn't possible because I have got an error, but I think you understand what I am trying to achieve. Let me clear it up, I can do :

```
a,b = 3+2,3
```

Edit ---> Or even better:

```
a,b = [0,1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I wan't a similar thing in my first code example. I am trying to assign variables 'a' and 'b' as list, with list comprehension, but using tuple as assignment, the point is I don't want to use this:

```
a = [i for in range(5)]
b = [i+1 for in range(5)]
```

I am aware that I can use this: `t = [(i,i+1) for i in range(5)]`, but that's not the point.
By the way this is only a simple example => "i,i+1"

Edit ---> I would like to clarify my question. How to assign several variables (type list) in one line, using list comprehension?

Comment: Don't ask hypothetical questions. Your real problem might very well quite a different solution than your simplified one.

Comment: See [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @hop: That's just a bad argument! The question is obvious : How to assign several variables using one loop and list comprehension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run this:

```
a,b = [(i,i+1) for i in range(5)] # wrapped i, i+1 in parentheses (syntax error)
```

It makes a list of five two-item tuples, like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

But you're trying to assign those five tuples to only two objects (`a` and `b`)

Using argument unpacking (*) in [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you can "unzip" the output to the first and second elements of *each* tuple:

```
a,b = zip(*[(i,i+1) for i in range(5)])
```

Which is this:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

And can be assigned to `a` and `b` as you've written

Comment: That's nice solution, thanks. I just wanna wait and see, if someone posts any better, until i accept the answer.

Comment: Didn't pay attention to the unzip option, zip(*..). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @hop, I fully agree, but OP did say "this is only simple example => "i,i+1"" so I assume there's more to it than we've seen

Comment: @mhlester: well then the question is worthless, isn't it?

Comment: @hop the question is how to unpack a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to be clever. This is perfectly acceptable code:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> b = range(1,6)
>>> a, b
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: I can say same for you too. My line : " By the way this is only simple example => "i,i+1" ". The point of this question is using only one loop and using list comprehension assign several variables.

Comment: :A simple one, indeed.