# Passing data from django model into a list

Tags: python, django, list, model

I'm trying to pass data from a db record into a list.

Here's my code: (it's inside my view)

```
dates_queryset = Profile.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    dates = []
    weights = []
    num = 1
    for qr in dates_queryset:
        dates.append(qr.date)
        weights.append(qr.weight)
        num += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django build-in method values_list() (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
dates_queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
dates = dates_queryset.values_list('date', flat=True)
weights = dates_queryset.values_list('weight', flat=True)
```

Also you don't need to select all objects first when you want to filter them (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Answer (score 0):

As Petr has already given you the (ideal) Django-style answer, here is a pythonic answer for how to get any iterable into a list using list comprehension.

```py
# Leave out .all(), if you already have .filter()
dates_queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

dates = [qr.date for qr in dates_queryset]
weights = [qr.weight for qr in dates_queryset]
num = len(dates_queryset)
```

You can shorten it further using zip(): [List comprehension with tuple assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493637/list-comprehension-with-tuple-assignment)

```py
dates_queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

dates, weights = zip(*[(qr.date, qr.weight) for qr in dates_queryset])
num = len(dates_queryset)
```